# How to get elements by style property value?

Tags: javascript

I need to get all div elements with "display: none" style and then remove all of these elements. Also i need to select just that divs which are contained in #somecontainer element. Have to do it in RAW javascript. Any idea?

example html:

```
    <table id="listtabletemp">
    <thead>
        <tr id="theader">
            <td id="theaderleft">loolz</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="" rel="13117025">
            <td><div><style>
.ikthgjyhtr{display:none}
.tVOx{display:inline}
</style>
                <div style="display:none">crap here</div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div style="display:none">crap here</div>
                <div class="230">something good</div>
                <div class="ikthgjyhtr">crap here</div>
                <div style="display:none">crap here</div>
                <div class="ikthgjyhtr">crap here</div>
                <div style="display: inline">something good</div>something good
                <div style="display: inline">something good</div>
                <div class="21">something good</div>
                <div style="display:none">crap here</div>
                <div style="display:none">crap here</div>
                <div style="display:none">crap here</div>
                <div class="4">something good</div>
                <div class="224">something good</div></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What do you mean by remove all these elements? Aren't they already removed if they have `display: none`. Or do you mean remove it entirely? In that case, just find the `div`s and delete 'em.

Comment: You you mean you want to remove the `el.style.display`? Btw: The actual term is "vanilla js": http://vanilla-js.com/ :)

Comment: @Kay From your comment, it seems like the term isn't vanilla js, because you link to a framework.

Comment: @hhamilton yeah … you didn't get the joke. ;) Scroll down a bit.

Comment: @Jacedc I need to remove them from dom tree. In jQuery equivalent looks: $("#gsdgbletemp").find(":hidden").remove();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, the DOM is your friend:

```
function removeDivs() {
    var container = document.getElementById("somecontainer");
    var divs = container.getElementsByTagName("div");
    var empty = [];
    var getStyle = function(obj, css){
        var style = null;
        if(obj.currentStyle) {
            style = obj.currentStyle[css];
        } else if(window.getComputedStyle) {
            style = window.getComputedStyle(obj, null).getPropertyValue(css);
        }
        return(style);
    };
    for(var i = 0, len = divs.length; i < len; i++) {
        var div = divs[i];
        if(div && ((div.style.display && div.style.display == "none") || getStyle(div, "display") == "none")) {
            empty.push(div);
        }
    }
    for(var i = 0, len = empty.length; i < len; i++) {
        var div = empty[i];
        div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need to check if the div has css style display:none assigned to it then it gets more complicated since the div.style.display==="" for css assigned display value.

Comment: @HMR good call on that; I have updated the function to take that into account.

Comment: @vladkras old habits die hard, but you make a solid point, that part is optional.

Comment: Also: should be `div.parentNode.removeChild(div)` since getElementsByTagName will return all divs deep under the container.

Comment: What @HMR means is, you have to check the computed value of display as it will be blank if set to none from an external CSS. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle

Comment: I had a feeling that's what he meant; however the op never specified an external force. I will throw in a function I have laying around. @bfavaretto

Comment: @faino Yep thanks for code. I was trying myself with getComputedStyle and querySelectorAll but i'm probably run-downed by insomnia... But still something doesn't work. Maybe i should add this with setinterveal (i writing some greasemonkey script).

Comment: After some testing with your provided HTML, I've edited my script to the point where is works as expected. Try the new version and let me know what you think @facebook-100000565381055

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty, here's something to get you started:

http://jsfiddle.net/kttsJ/

```
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
var items = parent.getElementsByTagName('DIV');
var hidden = [];
for (var i in items){
    if ((items[i]).getAttribute !== undefined){
        if ((items[i]).hasAttribute('style')){
            if ((/display\:\s*none/gi).test(items[i].getAttribute('style'))){
                hidden.push(items[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}

for (var i in hidden){
    hidden[i].parentNode.removeChild(hidden[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This removes divs with the "display: none" style. I tested it on the OP's example. Note: I added a "some-container" id when testing.

```js
function removeDivs() {
    "use strict";

    //Some container.
    const someContainer = document.getElementById("some-container");

    //Divs inside it.
    const divsInside = someContainer.querySelectorAll("div");

    //Loop, remove div if "display: none".
    divsInside.forEach(function (divInside) {
        const style = window.getComputedStyle(divInside);
        if (style.display === "none") {
            someContainer.removeChild(divInside);
        }
    });
}

removeDivs();
```

Comment: This seems like a well researched answer, but is rather verbose and doesn't directly solve the question. Can you adapt/edit it to just the parts needed to solve the initial question?

Comment: Scott, you're right. My answer should have been more concise, and targeted to the initial question. I re-did  my answer. I appreciate your guidance.